# How do I change attribute enclosed in parentheses in my Google Account?

Tags: google-account

How do I remove the name which has ()?

Please answer as soon as possible

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing this? In which application?

Comment: if you click this you will see where but you will need to sing in to a google account ---> https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info then there will be  "name" there you will see it

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid

Comment: Is that a google account nickname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "Nickname" field.

If you're seeing this line in the "Personal Info" page of accounts.google.com:

1. Click the "Go to About Me" link in a box below.
2. You'll reach https://myaccount.google.com/profile where you can edit the full profile information.
3. *Now* click on the "Name" row.
4. You'll be taken to https://myaccount.google.com/profile/name where you can edit or completely remove the nickname.

Comment: Thank you so so so so much! :)